# Unable to display a zero for capacity of a region

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am currently trying to solve this question:

> Determine the total capacity of the warehouses belonging to suppliers from a given nation in every region.  The suppliers’ nation is the United States.  If there are no warehouses in a region,  then value 0 is printed for that region. Print the region and the capacity sorted alphabetically by region.

This is the expected result:

```
region                           capacity
AFRICA                               4314
AMERICA                             10446
ASIA                                    0
EUROPE                               8402
MIDDLE EAST                         10866
```

So far I have done this for my SQL statement and I have most of it correct however I am not able to get ASIA to print 0 no matter what I tried.

```
select r_name, sum(w_capacity)
                  from warehouse,region,nation n1,nation n2,supplier
                        where w_suppkey = s_suppkey
                        AND w_nationkey = n2.n_nationkey
                        AND n1.n_nationkey = s_nationkey
                        AND n2.n_regionkey = r_regionkey
                        AND n1.n_name = "United States
                    group by r_name;
```

This is my result:

```
warehouse        capacity
AFRICA             4314
AMERICA            10446
EUROPE             8402
MIDDLE EAST       10866
```

Aliases for the tables used:

```
Warehouse table:                     
w_warehousekey decimal(9,0) not null,
w_name char(100) not null,
w_capacity decimal(6,0) not null,
w_suppkey decimal(9,0) not null,
w_nationkey decimal(2,0) not null
```

I used the TPC-H database. This link shows all the aliases for the tables I have available:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sample-data-tpch.html

Comment: Please add aliases to all of the tables so that I do not have to guess while proposing a coded solution.

Comment: I have edited my post. Sorry about that @Tarik

Comment: I have provided a simplified example that should help you get you through. I advise you to use the `join on` syntax that is more explicit and does not relegate the joint columns in the where clause where it does not belong. Please let me know if you are still stuck.

Comment: It would better to use `inner join, left join , ...` instead of `AND` anyway, you need to use 'left join' or `AND (+)` instead of `join` or `AND` for a table with no record during the join and also need to use `isnull(sum(w_capacity),0)`

Comment: I am still confused about how to add the left join in my code. Could you clarify it a bit more? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use left joins to ensure region is always included. The total for regions with no corresponding rows will be null. To overcome that use the IFNULL function.

Example:

```
Region
RegionID RegionName
1          Europe
2.         Americas

Sales
Date     RegionID Amount
1/1/2020 1          10
2/1/2020 1          20

SELECT r.RegionName, IFNULL(SUM(s.Amount), 0) AS Amount
FROM region r LEFT JOIN sales s ON r.RegionID= s.RegionID
GROUP BY RegionName

Expected result:
RegionName Amount
Europe     30
Americas   0
```